# how to convert a list lists of tuples to a list of lists?

Tags: python

I'm new to programming, and I need some help.
I have a list like this

```
a=[[('the', 'b'), ('hotel', 'i')],[('the', 'b'), ('staff', 'i')]]
```

and I'm trying to get rid of the tuple while retaining the data in a list, the outcome should look like this

```
output=[['the', 'b', 'hotel', 'i'],['the', 'b', 'staff', 'i']]
```

Thank you so much

Comment: The keyword you're missing for your searches is "flatten", as in "how to flatten a list".

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following list comprehension:

```
>>> [[y for x in i for y in x] for i in a]
[['the', 'b', 'hotel', 'i'], ['the', 'b', 'staff', 'i']]
```

Note that this has nothing to do with tuples, which because of duck typing are treated the exact same way as lists in a list comprehension. You are essentially doing the operation described in [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python) over multiple list items.

Answer (score 1):

This can be accomplished via the `sum` function:

```
a=[[('the', 'b'), ('hotel', 'i')],[('the', 'b'), ('staff', 'i')]]
output = [sum(elem, ()) for elem in a]
print(output)
```

And if it must return a list:

```
a=[[('the', 'b'), ('hotel', 'i')],[('the', 'b'), ('staff', 'i')]]
output = [sum(map(list,elem), []) for elem in a]
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use:

```
output = []
for x in a:
    output.append([element for tupl in x for element in tupl])
```

---

outputs:

```
[['the', 'b', 'hotel', 'i'], ['the', 'b', 'staff', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a "functional"-style variant of @nfn neil's A.

```
from itertools import repeat

list(map(list, map(sum, a, repeat(()))))
# -> [['the', 'b', 'hotel', 'i'], ['the', 'b', 'staff', 'i']]
```